# C++: boost/filesystem: some questions

Tags: c++, boost

I am using Boost library in C++ running in Ubuntu enviroment. I have some questions that I am not clear about:

1. `fs::is_directory`

   ```
   namespace fs = boost::filesystem;


   fs::path full_path(fs::initial_path<fs::path>() );


   full_path = fs::system_complete(fs::path( "temp/"));


   if(fs::is_directory(full_path ))
   {
      cout << "the path is a directory" << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "the path is not a directory" << endl;
   }
   ```

   => I am sure that the moment I am running the program, there is a directory temp at the same location with the executable file. But it is always returned: "the path is not a directory" ?
2. `fs::last_write_time`

   - Is this `fs::last_write_time(path)` be able to get the last date time of modifying for the given path for BOTH either a directory or a file?
   - If it is true also for a directory, is that true for only the directory when it was created or the last date time if I add a file to inside the folder as well?
3. `fs::directory_iterator`

   - `fs::directory_iterator dir(full_path)` => how can I check whether this 'dir' has any sub directories or not?
4. Is there any way in boost::fileSystem to check if a file is opening?

Thanks in advance and I hope you could help me to make my mind clear!

Comment: `/tmp` is a directory, but is `temp/` a directory?

Comment: I re-formatted your question, check how its source code now looks :)

Comment: thanks Pavels! I reupdated my question as well

Comment: Instead of just thanking him, how about continuing the job, and formatting the *new* code you wrote? ;) (for small inline code snippets, surround them by \`backticks\`, for code blocks, indent it by 4 spaces, in both cases, select it and click the `101010` button)

Comment: Not sure it helps, but here is some code that recursively finds all files in a directory, using Boost.Filesystem v3: https://github.com/dlidstrom/freedb/blob/master/freedb-pp/freedbpp/main.cpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Seems like that should work. Why don't you put a `cout << fullpath` before the if to make sure the path really contains what you think it does?
2. I've never used last_write_time. Can't help you with that one.
3. You have to iterate over the directory's contents and use `fs::is_directory(dir->status())` to determine whether a given directory entry is a directory or not. (assuming dir is your directory iterator)
4. I don't believe there is anything in boost::filesystem to tell you if a file is open or not.

Comment: Thanks for your concise comment!

Comment: Anyone, please help with question 2 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

re 4.: Can't you find out if a file is currently open by simply calling `[boost::filesystem|std]::fstream::is_open()`?